# How to configure AOSP for a Bluetooth Chip without BLE Support (e.g., CC2564) on Android 8.0?"

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-source, gatt

I'm currently working on integrating a Bluetooth chip, specifically the CC2564, into an Android Open Source Project (AOSP) environment running Android 8.0. The Bluetooth stack I'm utilizing is Fluoride, which unfortunately lacks comprehensive documentation.

My issue arises from the fact that the CC2564 chip does not support Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). Despite specifying in my device definition that GATT is not supported, Bluetooth still crashes during initialization. Upon examining the Bluetooth adapter's state machine in AdapterState.java, it seems that transitioning to BLE ON is mandatory during the adapter's startup sequence. Since my hardware lacks BLE support, Bluetooth fails to initialize and never fully starts up.

[Adapter State Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udVIu.png)

I've attempted configuration adjustments through bdroid_buildcfg.h, but none seem to address the absence of BLE support explicitly.

How can I properly configure my AOSP environment to accommodate a Bluetooth chip without BLE support? Are there any specific settings or modifications within the AOSP source code that I need to implement to prevent Bluetooth from crashing during initialization due to the absence of BLE support? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your "facts" are wrong, the CC2564 supports both BLE and EDR.  [CC2564 data sheet](https://www.ti.com/product/CC2564)